# GridView update works on site but does not work in popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My GridView is too big to show it on site, so i decided to show and edit it int popup.
I put gridView and sqlConnection inside

```
<div id ="popup" style="display:none; font-size:15px">
</div>
```

I use this code to show grid after press edit:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string myScript = null;
        myScript = "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        myScript += "\n$(\"#popup\").dialog({";
        myScript += "\ntitle: \"Displaying GridView Data\",";
        myScript += "\nwidth: '95%',";
        myScript += "\n});";
        myScript += "\n</script>\n";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", myScript, false);
    }
```

When I Edit this gridView on site (without popup) all works fine, but when i edit it inside popup, i got message that update function send there null value:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Ilosc', table 'sklepOlimpijski.dbo.Koszyk'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Update command:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE Koszyk SET Ilosc = @Ilosc, Kwota = Produkt.Cena * @Ilosc, adresWysylki = @adresWysylki, czyWyslano = @czyWyslano, czyTowarDostepny = @czyTowarDostepny, czyOplacono = @czyOplacono FROM Koszyk INNER JOIN Produkt ON Koszyk.IdProduktu = Produkt.ID WHERE (Koszyk.ID = @ID)"
```

So i think Update command cannot take @ values from popup windows. How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0):

keep "@" in front of the Query

```
  UpdateCommand=@"UPDATE Koszyk SET Ilosc = @Ilosc, Kwota = Produkt.Cena * @Ilosc, adresWysylki = @adresWysylki, czyWyslano = @czyWyslano, czyTowarDostepny = @czyTowarDostepny, czyOplacono = @czyOplacono FROM Koszyk INNER JOIN Produkt ON Koszyk.IdProduktu = Produkt.ID WHERE (Koszyk.ID = @ID)"
```

Comment: It's not working. This command is set in .aspx file. I'm not setting it in code behind. If i put @ before "Update, visual studio throw errors.